# Issues constructing keras layers and adding to a model at run time

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

As part of my dissertation I am creating a hyperparameter optimisation library; as part of this I am trying to construct Keras layers at runtime and add them to a model. However, when I run the model it doesn't seem to train, the accuracy and validation accuracy stay at 0.5. If I define an array of layers that is static in the code it trains fine. The code below highlights the two approaches.

The dynamic approach uses a layer object that contains the layer types, its hyperparameters and non-hyperparamaters, these are iterated and added to the model in order:

```html
import tensorflow as tf

self._model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
for layer in self._layers:
    print(layer)
    params = layer.all_parameters()
    print(params)
    self._model.add(layer._layer_type(**params))

self._model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
self._model.summary()
```

Model summary:

```html
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 200, 200, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 100, 100, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 100, 100, 32)      4640      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 50, 50, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 50, 50, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 25, 25, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 25, 25, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 12, 12, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 18432)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 18432)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 512)               9437696   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               131328    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 514       
=================================================================
Total params: 9,666,978
Trainable params: 9,666,978
Non-trainable params: 0
```

A single epoch (all 10 epochs are roughly the same):

```html
700/700 [==============================] - 70s 100ms/step - loss: 7.7036 - accuracy: 0.4985 - val_loss: 7.6916 - val_accuracy: 0.4999
```

The summary matches exactly what the static version (see below) outputs.

Static version:

```html
self._model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
  layers = [
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(200, 200, 3)),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5, seed=42),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5, seed=42),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3, seed=42),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')
  ]
  for layer in layers:
      self._model.add(layer)

  self._model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
  self._model.summary()
```

Model Summary:

```html
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 200, 200, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 100, 100, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 100, 100, 32)      4640      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 50, 50, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 50, 50, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 25, 25, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 25, 25, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 12, 12, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 18432)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 18432)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 512)               9437696   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               131328    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 514       
=================================================================
Total params: 9,666,978
Trainable params: 9,666,978
Non-trainable params: 0
```

One epoch (the rest carry on training as expected):

```html
700/700 [==============================] - 70s 100ms/step - loss: 0.5455 - accuracy: 0.7083 - val_loss: 0.4870 - val_accuracy: 0.7585
```

I have no idea what could be causing this, it's like the layers never update.

A more complete example code:

```html
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class Parameter:
    def __init__(self, name, value, value_range=None, constraints=None):
        self._name = name
        self._value = value
        self._value_range = value_range
        self._constraints = constraints

    def get_key_val_pair(self):
        return (self._name, self._value)

    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def value(self, value=None):
        if not value is None:
            self._value = value

        return self._value

    def value_range(self):
        return self._value_range

    def constraints(self):
        return self._constraints

class Layer:
    def __init__(self, layer_name, layer_type, parameters=[], hyperparameters=[]):
        self._layer_type = layer_type
        self._parameters = parameters
        self._hyperparameters = hyperparameters

    def all_parameters(self):
        paramaters = dict()
        keyVals = [param.get_key_val_pair() for param in self._parameters + self._hyperparameters]
        if len(keyVals) > 0:
            paramaters.update(keyVals)

        return paramaters

model_layers = [
    #0 - Conv 2D - Optimise
    Layer(layer_name="input_layer", layer_type=tf.keras.layers.Conv2D,
    hyperparameters=[], 
    parameters=[
        Parameter(name="filters", value=16, value_range=[2**x for x in range(1, 7)], constraints=None),# range from 2-128
        Parameter(name="kernel_size", value=3, value_range=range(2, 11), constraints=None),#kernal size range from 2 to 10
        Parameter(name="padding", value="same", value_range=["same"], constraints=None),#need to add more
        Parameter(name="activation", value="relu", value_range=["relu", "tanh", "sigmoid"], constraints=None),#need to add more
        Parameter(name="input_shape", value=(200, 200, 3))
    ]),

    #1 - Max Pooling 2D - No Optimisation Currently - TODO
    Layer(layer_name="hidden_layer_1", layer_type=tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D, 
    hyperparameters=[], 
    parameters=[]),

    #2 - Conv 2D - Optimise
    Layer(layer_name="hidden_layer_2", layer_type=tf.keras.layers.Conv2D, 
    hyperparameters=[],
    parameters=[
        Parameter(name="filters", value=32, value_range=[2**x for x in range(1, 7)], constraints=None),# range from 2-128
        Parameter(name="kernel_size", value=3, value_range=range(2, 11), constraints=None),#kernal size range from 2 to 10
        Parameter(name="padding", value="same", value_range=["same"], constraints=None),#need to add more
        Parameter(name="activation", value="relu", value_range=["relu", "tanh", "sigmoid"], constraints=None)#need to add more
    ]),

    #3 - Max Pooling 2D - No Optimisation Currently - TODO
    Layer(layer_name="hidden_layer_3", layer_type=tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D, 
    parameters=[], 
    hyperparameters=[]),

    #4 - Conv 2D - Optimise
    Layer(layer_name="hidden_layer_4", layer_type=tf.keras.layers.Conv2D, 
    hyperparameters=[],
    parameters=[
        Parameter(name="filters", value=64, value_range=[2**x for x in range(1, 7)], constraints=None),# range from 2-128
        Parameter(name="kernel_size", value=3, value_range=range(2, 11), constraints=None),#kernal size range from 2 to 10
        Parameter(name="padding", value="same", value_range=["same"], constraints=None),#need to add more
        Parameter(name="activation", value="relu", value_range=["relu", "tanh", "sigmoid"], constraints=None)#need to add more
    ]),

    #5 - Max Pooling 2D - No Optimisation Currently - TODO
    Layer(layer_name="hidden_layer_5", layer_type=tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D, 
    hyperparameters=[], 
    parameters=[]),

    #6 - Conv 2D - Optimise
    Layer(layer_name="hidden_layer_6", layer_type=tf.keras.layers.Conv2D, 
    hyperparameters=[],
    parameters=[
        Parameter(name="filters", value=128, value_range=[2**x for x in range(1, 7)], constraints=None),# range from 2-128
        Parameter(name="kernel_size", value=3, value_range=range(2, 11), constraints=None),#kernal size range from 2 to 10
        Parameter(name="padding", value="same", value_range=["same"], constraints=None),#need to add more
        Parameter(name="activation", value="relu", value_range=["relu", "tanh", "sigmoid"], constraints=None)#need to add more
    ]),

    #7 - Max Pooling 2D - No Optimisation Currently - TODO
    Layer(layer_name="hidden_layer_7", layer_type=tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D, 
    hyperparameters=[], 
    parameters=[]),

    #8 - Flatten - No Optimisation Currently - TODO
    Layer(layer_name="hidden_layer_8", layer_type=tf.keras.layers.Flatten, 
    hyperparameters=[], 
    parameters=[]),

    #9 - Dropout - Optimise
    Layer(layer_name="hidden_layer_9", layer_type=tf.keras.layers.Dropout, 
    parameters=[
        Parameter(name="seed", value=42),
        Parameter(name="rate", value=0.2, value_range=np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01).tolist(), constraints=None)
    ], 
    hyperparameters=[
        
    ]),

    #10 - Dense - Optimise
    Layer(layer_name="hidden_layer_10", layer_type=tf.keras.layers.Dense, 
    parameters=[
        Parameter(name="units", value=512, value_range=[2**x for x in range(2, 10)], constraints=None),#range between 4 and 512
        Parameter(name="activation", value="relu", value_range=["relu", "tanh", "sigmoid"], constraints=None)#need to add more
    ], 
    hyperparameters=[
    ]),

    #11 - Dropout - Optimise
    Layer(layer_name="hidden_layer_11", layer_type=tf.keras.layers.Dropout, 
    parameters=[
        Parameter(name="seed", value=42),
        Parameter(name="rate", value=0.2, value_range=np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01).tolist(), constraints=None)
    ], 
    hyperparameters=[
        
    ]),

    #12 - Dense - Optimise
    Layer(layer_name="hidden_layer_12", layer_type=tf.keras.layers.Dense, 
    hyperparameters=[], 
    parameters=[
        Parameter(name="units", value=256, value_range=[2**x for x in range(2, 10)], constraints=None),#range between 4 and 512
        Parameter(name="activation", value="relu", value_range=["relu", "tanh", "sigmoid"], constraints=None)#need to add more
    ]),

    #13 - Dropout - Optimise
    Layer(layer_name="hidden_layer_12", layer_type=tf.keras.layers.Dropout, 
    parameters=[
        Parameter(name="seed", value=42),
        Parameter(name="rate", value=0.2 , value_range=np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01).tolist(), constraints=None)
    ], 
    hyperparameters=[
        
    ]),

    #14 - Dense - Optimise
    Layer(layer_name="output_layer", layer_type=tf.keras.layers.Dense, 
    parameters=[
        Parameter(name="units", value=2),
        Parameter(name="activation", value="relu", value_range=["relu", "tanh", "sigmoid"], constraints=None)#need to add more
    ], 
    hyperparameters=[
        
    ])
]

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
for layer in model_layers:
    print(layer)
    params = layer.all_parameters()
    print(params)
    model.add(layer._layer_type(**params))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Repositories for the complete code:

[Hyperparameter optimisation library](https://github.com/robertbennett1998/hyperparameter_optimisation_library)

[Cats and Dogs model code](https://github.com/robertbennett1998/CatsAndDogsHpo)

Comment: Can you provide an example that we can run to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have edited adding a generic example which summarises the code and links to the actual repositories.

Comment: Seems your dynamic model does not have the same hyperparameters than your static model, for example the activation at the output layer is ReLU in your dynamic model, but sigmoid in the dynamic model. Those differences could explain the problem.

Comment: Thank you, good spot; this has had me stumped. Very silly mistake...